# A closed form of $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+id)$

Tags: factorial, closed-form, products, arithmetic-progressions

for positive integers $a$ and $d$ I need a general formula involving factorials for this product:$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+id)$$( For example for $a=1$ and $d=2$ the product is equal to $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$ )

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+id)=d^n\cdot\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac ad+i\right)
$$ then one may recall that
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x+i)=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}
$$ see for example the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Examples).