# Finding the expression for the power series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\prod _{i=0}^{n-1} (a+id)}{\prod _{i=1}^n id}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let
$$f(x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\prod _{i=0}^{n-1} (a+id)}{\prod _{i=1}^n id}x^n$$ where $d > 0$, $a+nd\neq 0$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

From Mathematica, I was able to get $f(x) = (1-x)^{-\frac{a}{d}}-1$. Would anyone help me or provide a hint on how to simplify $f(x)$? Many thanks.

Comment: I'll just note that the denominator of the fraction can be simplified to $b^n \cdot n!$, assuming that $b$ is supposed to be in the product, otherwise it's $b \cdot n!$. And it seems like there is a closed form for the numerator using the Gamma function: [A closed form of $\prod\_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+id)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2598908)

Comment: The lack of $d$ in your final result is troubling though. The uniqueness of power series coefficients would heavily suggest that the expression of your function feature $d$ in some fashion?

Comment: This is not what Mathematica returns. Would you write the syntax you used ?

Comment: @BrunoB. The result is very simple but does not have anything to do with what is written in the post (even if similar)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My apologies. It seems like I previously forgot to clear some variables. I have updated the computed result.

Comment: Your expression for $f(x)$ seems to be as simple as it can possibly be. For general values of $a,d$ it can't be simplified. For specific values, it may be barely possible. For example, if $a/d = -1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the changes the OP has made to the post, the given power series is just a [generalized binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) which skips the $0$-th term. Let $a/d=r$.

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+id)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(id)}x^n\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(a+d)(a+2d)\cdots(a+(n-1)d)}{n!\cdot d^n}x^n\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+(n-1))}{n!}x^n\\  &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-r(-r-1)(-r-2)\cdots(-r-(n-1))}{n!}(-x)^n\\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{-r}{n}(-x)^n \\&= \sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty\binom{-r}{n}(-x)^n-1 \\ &= (1-x)^{-r}-1 \ \forall \ |x|<1\quad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Also, the constraints don't make much sense.

- It is not necessary to have $d > 0$ as long as $d\neq 0$.
- $a+nd\neq 0$ is not necessary either.
- The series doesn't converge for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the answer.